# Vuetify: Error when overriding component-specific SASS variable

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I follow the official guide on how to override Vuetify SASS variables ([link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/)) which says:

> Create a main.scss file in your src/styles directory and update the
> style import within your vuetify.js file:

src/styles/main.scss

```
@use 'vuetify' with (
  $app-bar-background: 'red';
);
```

src/plugins/vuetify.ts

```
import '@/styles/main.scss'
```

However, I receive this error message on application startup:

```
[sass] This variable was not declared with !default in the @used module.
  ╷
2 │     $app-bar-background: 'red'
  │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/styles/main.scss 2:5  root stylesheet
10:58:31 AM [vite] Internal server error: [sass] This variable was not declared with !default in the @used module.
  ╷
2 │     $app-bar-background: 'red'
  │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/styles/main.scss 2:5  root stylesheet
  Plugin: vite:css
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a bit confusing. From what I understand, the issue comes from import order, it only affects component variables. The documentation has a [section about it](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#component-specific-variables).

To fix it, you have to load the styles through the vuetify-loader Vite plugin (I suppose it is the same with Webpack). The [documentation](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/master/packages/vite-plugin#customising-variables) is a bit sparse, I'll add a word on each step:

1. Create a file with the component-specific overrides, using `vuetify/settings`:

```scss
// vuetify-settings.scss
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
  $app-bar-background: 'red',
);
```

2. Inside Vite configuration, register the file with the vuetify-loader plugin using `styles.configFile`:

```js
// vite.config.js
plugins: [
  vue(),
  vuetify({
    styles: {
      configFile: './src/vuetify-settings.scss'
    }
  }),
]
```

3. Switch back to the regular style import:

```js
// plugins/vuetify.js
import 'vuetify/styles' // <----
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify()
```

Now the loader will compile the CSS file and inject it into the build.

Here it is in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-mestorf-7g5ssn?file=/vite.config.js:13,38)